# How to use IBM DB2 on IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, db2

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1 on Ubuntu. How do I go about connecting to IBM DB2 Database. I notice it only caters for Oracle, MySQL, SQLite and PostgreSQL. Is there a way in which I can perhaps get a plugin or a .jar file to achieve this.

Comment: Database support is available only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (see comparison matrix [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)). And it does support DB2 databases. See [Defining a database](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/2017.1/getting-started-with-datagrip.html#define_database) in a related web help for the steps.
With the Community Edition you may consider using [Database Navigator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1800-database-navigator) 3rd plugin.

Comment: I'm not sure how one creates a connection to a custom database with it. Please refer to Plugin's documentation

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Andrey, install Database navigator, download appropriate jdbc driver from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.db2.jcc/db2jcc/db2jcc4)
(refraining from posting images, as steps easy to perform).

Go to database navigator,

1. click on create new connection
2. give a name to the connection
   3.use appropriate jdbc url jdbc:db2://localhost:32771/dbname
3. choose appropriate username and password -> browse and provide the downloaded jdbc jar
4. choose the driver.

I think that should work for you.